# Fuelux DataGrid obtain selected row

Tags: fuelux

Is it possible to selected a row in Fuelux datagrid and obtain the results on button clicked event?

For Example:

I wanna selected a row and obtain the results on a button click. The results will be than sent to a MVC controller.

Is this possible? google didn't really help on this.

**Answer**

Hah! found the answer:

https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/172